# handleInputChange - React Redux File Upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, file-io

I am trying to upload a file and update the state with the file object that was uploaded.

The console logs after setState show the state has not been updated.

Anytime I try to console.log the event for the file upload onChange I get a circular JSON reference and if I try to log event.target I get undefined.

How do I write the uploaded file to the state?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

class FileUpload extends Component {

  state = {
    myPicture: {}
  };

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))

  }

  render() {
    const {myPicture} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>

        {JSON.stringify(this.state.myPicture)}

        <input
          accept="image/*"
          className={"fileInput"}
          id="myPicture"
          multiple
          type="file"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="myPicture">
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
            Upload Picture
          </Button>
        </label>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    myPicture: state.auth.myPicture,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FileUpload);
```

Comment: `console.log` after `setState` NEVER shows updated value - read docs

Comment: @xadm Why didn’t the stringified this.state.myPicture update in the return?

Comment: hint: `event.target.files[0]` or sth like that ... search about handling uploads/input file type etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly reference the array of files or the file itself.

You must reference specific keys from the event.target.files[0].

Example after file upload:

- Ex: `JSON.stringify(event.target.files[0]) === {}`
- Ex:    `JSON.stringify(event.target.files[0].name ===
  'myFileNameHere'`